# TableView constructible content | Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I'm working on an app, where admin-side is based on creation articles. Have 2 buttons - add image and text view. The order of adding is absolutely random, i.e. image-image-image-text / text-image-image etc.

I don't understand how to make it and add to a cell. 
Adding an image:

[image: prototype]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this Problem you have to make **Custom UITableViewCell** to add Image and textview.

After that you have prepare one array to add button which is clicked by user.(if button image press then i will add value “**Image**”  and if textView button press then i will add value “**TextView**”)

And finally on the basis of that array you can return **UITableViewCell**.

This is the button click event

```
@IBAction func btnImageCliked(sender :UIButton)
{
  self.testArray.addObject("Image")
  self.tblCustom?.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func btnTextViewCliked(sender :UIButton)
{
    self.testArray.addObject("TextView")
    self.tblCustom?.reloadData()
}
```

Create Custom UITableViewCell object  like this way,

```
  var imgCell : imageCell = imageCell()
  var txtCell : textViewCell = textViewCell()
```

And you can fill UITableView In this Way,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.testArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let nib: NSArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)
    if(testArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String == "Image")
    {
        imgCell = (nib.objectAtIndex(0) as? imageCell)!
        return imgCell
    }
    else
    {
        txtCell = (nib.objectAtIndex(1) as? textViewCell)!
         return txtCell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```